# Deleting Linked Lists of Linked Lists structure

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have the following structure that I need to delete

```
typedef struct
{
    exampleList*    pNext;      /* pointer to next entry */
    exampleList*    pSublist1;  /* pointer to 'sublist1' list */
    exampleList*    pSublist2;  /* pointer to 'sublist2' list */
    exampleList*    pSublist3;  /* pointer to 'sublist3' list */

    //Other data
    . . .
    } exampleList;
```

I know I can do this using recursion, as below.

```
void exampleClass::delete(exampleList* sampleList)
{
    if (sampleList->pNext)     delete(sampleList->pNext);
    if (sampleList->pSublist1) delete(sampleList->pSublist1);
    if (sampleList->pSublist2) delete(sampleList->pSublist2);
    if (sampleList->pSublist3) delete(sampleList->pSublist3);

    //cleanup code
    . . .
}
```

The problem with this approach is that I have a large number of items in each list and this can overflow the stack.

Also forgot to mention that these List's are working in shared memory, so if something happens to this process I want to ensure that I don't lose track of the chain.

Do you know of the simplest alternate way to delete this structure?

Comment: You're using C++. Stop managing memory manually. Make the struct members `std::unique_ptr<exampleList>` instead of `exampleList*` (or `std::shared_ptr<exampleList>`, depending on needs). `unique_ptr` in particular is zero overhead relative to manual pointer management, and removes the need to deal with this nonsense (you probably wouldn't even require a hand written destructor at all).

Comment: @MitchWheat: I think the OP means that the recursion involved can actually exhaust the stack when the linked list is long (so delete of node 1 deletes node 2 which deletes node 3 ... which deletes node 500 million and somewhere along the way, the 10-40 MB of stack is exhausted). That might be a reasonable fear, depending on use case. Don't know if compiler will effectively optimize out the recursion.

Comment: use of recursion depends on how computationally expensive is the method. In your case you are invoking delete on each object of list, you will get better performance using for_each.

Comment: `exampleClass::delete`. Have you tried to compile it? :)

Comment: @ShadowRanger `unique_ptr` probably won't save this construction from stack overflow.

Comment: Well, depends whether the compiler can recognize the construct and do tail call optimization. Not something I'd rely on even if certain compilers do support it though. That said, I think even conservatively, you'd need to have somewhere in the six figure range entries in the linked list at destruction time before recursion issues came up, and the overhead for managing them as a linked list (instead of something sane with block allocation like `deque` typically uses) would be completely out of control.

Comment: @ShadowRanger To make tail call optimizations one needs tail calls to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one method (not tested).

```
void free_list (exampleList* root)
{
  std::queue<exampleList*> q;
  if (root) q.push_back(root);
  while (!q.empty())
  {
    exampleList* node = q.pop_front();
    if (node->pNext) q.push_back(node->pNext);
    if (node->pSublist1) q.push_back(node->pSublist1);
    if (node->pSublist2) q.push_back(node->pSublist2);
    if (node->pSublist3) q.push_back(node->pSublist3);
    delete node;
  }
}
```

This should easily adapt to lists that use `unique_ptr`.

A side note: your structure is actually more like a tree than a list.

Comment: Hi n.m. Thanks for your response. This is the kind of answer I was looking for although I inexplicably forgot to mention that I'm working in shared memory so I need to keep track of where I'm up to if the process is interrupted midway through.